# Apache Spark: why spark create multiple stages to scan a hive table even cached and why repartition can solve that?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

My Questions are:

1. why spark create multiple stages to scan a hive table, even though I
   already cache the dataframe?
2. why the number of stages is reduced when I repartition the dataframe before cache?

Scenario 1(sudo code):

```
large_source_df.cache, 
small_source1_df.cache, 
small_source2_df.cache
small_source3_df.cache

res1_df = large_source_df.join(broadcast(small_source1_df)).filter(...)
res2_df = large_source_df.join(broadcast(small_source2_df)).filter(...)
res3_df = large_source_df.join(broadcast(small_source3_df)).filter(...)

union_df = res1_df.union(res2_df).union(res3_df).count
```

in this case, the large_source_df is used three times, even though it is cached, looks like the hive table is scanned 3 times.
[image]

Scenario 2(sudo code):
if I changed the code, and add repartition between cache,

```
large_source_df.repartition(200, $"userid").cache, 
small_source1_df.cache, 
small_source2_df.cache
small_source3_df.cache

res1_df = large_source_df.join(broadcast(small_source1_df)).filter(...)
res2_df = large_source_df.join(broadcast(small_source2_df)).filter(...)
res3_df = large_source_df.join(broadcast(small_source3_df)).filter(...)

union_df = res1_df.union(res2_df).union(res3_df).count
```

it only scan the table once. 
[image]

Comment: pyspark.......?

Comment: not pyspark, scala-spark

Comment: can you confirm the data is read from disk and not from cache, besides the dag UI?

Comment: @shay__ I don't have other ways to confirm that. Do you have any ideas of confirming that?

Comment: there are some ways, but first please add the plan for this job. You can find it in `SQL` tab on the UI. go to the query that contains the job number and find the plan at the bottom

Comment: in any case, it makes sense that `repartition` results in just one branch since the `cache` is made on the result, which is past the table scan.

Comment: hard to follow without seeing the actual code

Comment: Hello @AlanLi I update my answer below since I realized that it was too broad regarding the first part of your question. I hope it helps to clarify things more than before :)